# PhpStorm not highlighting PHP code inside a .php file when mixed with HTML

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I am having a problem in PHPStorm where it won't highlight PHP code (but will intellisense it) inside a .php file when it's mixed with HTML code.

Screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image: Screenshot]

If I invalidate cache/restart, it will, for a few seconds, show the correct highlighting. However, after it "calculates", it will return to not highlighting it.

Is there a setting for this? Or is it just a plain bug?

I have read about language injections, but this does not seem like the place for it since it's a .php file already and PHP is not on the list of injectable languages.

Relevant code:

```
<?php
$works = "yes";
?>

<html>
<body>

<script>
    var shouldStillWorkAfterThis = true;
</script>

<?php
$works = "yes";
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $works = "yes"; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- lets try split syntax -->
<?php
if ($works) {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $works ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php $thisShouldToo = true; ?>
<?php } ?>

<!-- lets break it -->
<div id="someclass">
    <header>
        <div class="someotherclass">
            <div class="andanextraclass">
                <!-- include a file-->
                <?php include('somefile.php');?>
                <?php
                    $anythingHereIsNowBroken = true;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Language Injections Settings:

[image: Language Injections]

I am using PhpStorm 8.0.3 on MacOSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Try reducing some of the HTML above the PHP code and see if you can still reproduce the issue. Then, post all the code in the file so that we can try reproducing it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Screenshot of your `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Language Injections` please.

Comment: Here you go : http://puu.sh/i5JQd/458618c38e.png

Comment: Here is a test file : http://pastebin.com/Z3hMY4ur and related screenshot : http://puu.sh/i5JZO/b1532e72c6.png

Comment: Please update your question with all the new information that you have. You can [edit] your question by clicking on "[edit]" under the question.

Comment: Please also provide the version number of your PhpStorm, and the environment that you are running PhpStorm on.

Comment: Already have, thank you.

Comment: Can't this be a color scheme problem?

Comment: How so? Shouldn't php code be highlighted as is in other places ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on your screenshot of `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Language Injections`.

**Please delete 3rd language injection rule from the bottom** (the one for "div" -- that has "IDE" in Scope column).

That rule injects HTML into `div` tag which tells IDE to treat all other code (even PHP) inside such tag as HTML/plain text.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. Thank you :) Here is how it looks afterwards: http://puu.sh/i5L8D/d8cffe4471.png

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also helped me :-)

Comment: Perfect solution. After more than year of this answer it solved my problem. I am using PHPStorm 2016.3 in Windows.