# JetBrains WebStorm comment shortcut is wrong for html

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using JetBrains WebStorm 2016.3.3 and I use shortcut for comment lines.

When I type `CTRL + /` in  tag of HTML file, it writes: `/*  my comment */`

But it should be `<!- my comment -->`

I did not understand how it happened, it was working before.

[image]

And my Settings are like this:

[image]

Comment: does it happen in html or template file? in `<script>` tag, or in HTML context? Please attach a screenshot that shows up the issue

Comment: I noticed after you said that, it happens in <head> element of html file. The issue is not occured out of the <head> element.

Comment: can't recreate. seems you have some language injected in <head> element. Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: post updated with screenshot

Comment: @bookmarker Please post screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections` (similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30544613/783119)

Comment: Ok updated the post with settings screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`
2. Delete 3rd rule from the bottom -- the one that has `IDE` in Scope column.

You've somehow created injection rule that injects CSS inside `<head>` tag (*most likely you were typing too fast without looking at what's happening on the screen*).