# PhpStorm SQL highlight wrong part of code

Tags: phpstorm

I did something wrong and now it's impossible to fix the issue.

PhpStorm is highlighting in yellow also the part of code is not SQL.
If I click on the bulb it says "Edit <Generic SQL> Fragment".
I tried to delete to code and rewrite but as soon as I write the same code it starts to highlight it, also if I create another file...

I don't want to disable highlighting or language injection, I just want to tell the editor that that part is not SQL and get back to the normal black background, like inside the `<ol>` tag.

[image: PhpStorm SQL highlight error]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30544613/783119 -- delete wrongly created rule.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne! This fixed my problem